# Can't apply CSS Float

Tags: html, css

First off, I'm new and just started coding. For some reason, I cannot apply the CSS float class to the image. Anytime I try to load the float class, it simply will not load for me.

Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Lab3-2</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: Arial,Verdana,Garamond;
                font-size: 11pt;
            }

            h1,
            h2,
            h3 {
                color: #19212d;
            }

            ul {
                list-style-type: square;
            }

            a {
                color: black;
            }

            a:hover {
                background: #19212d;
                color: white;
            }

            span {
                color: #19212D;
                font-weight: bold
            }

            .align-right {
                float: right;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }

            .align-left {
                float: left;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tierra Peak Hiking</h1>
        <p>
            <span>Tierra Peak Hiking</span> arranges a wide variety of day hikes for families, friends, and teams. 
            Imagine yourself hiking along a creek or viewing the beauty of the valley from the peak of a hiking trail. Stop by one of our offices.
        </p>

        <h3>Things to see:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Icicle Creek</li>
            <li>View the Valley</li>
        </ul>

        <img class="align-left" src="/creek.jpg" width="259" height="387" alt="creek" />
        <p>
            Take a long hike along Icicle Creek and watch the majestic waters flow. Enjoy the soothing sounds of the rushing water while standing amidst the surrounding trees.
            This hike is rated a double-boot because the climbing is moderately strenuous. However, the land immediately around the creek is flat and allows for frequent rest stops.
        </p>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to set the image as a block, `display: block`. Because image default behavior is as a `inline` element and it's not able to float, you need to ser the floating element as a block.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8eqoowy4/  I don't see the problem.

Comment: What is expected and what is currently happening?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird It loads correctly on jsfiddle.net, but when I try to open it with Edge or Chrome, the text doesn't float around the image.

Comment: Maybe you can add an image of what you are seeing and what you expect.   This code floats the image fine for me in Chrome both on jsfiddle and on my local server.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird What I'm expecting is what you posted. Instead, I am going this https://jsfiddle.net/rbLjccwj/

Comment: Is your page exacly what you have entered here?  Or could there be additional CSS applied to it?  Are you including any other files or using this in a wordpress site?

Comment: Yes and there is no additional CSS applied to it.  I am using Notepad++ for coding.  I ran it through the validator and it showed no errors in the file.